# Two circles touch internally at X and a straight line cuts them at A, B, C, D in order. Prove that AB, CD subtend equal angles at X.

Tags: geometry, contest-math

Two circles touch internally at X and a straight line cuts them at A, B, C, D in order. Prove that AB, CD subtend equal angles at X.

Source: Challenge and Thrills in Pre College Mathematics.

> [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
Let $AD$ intersect the smaller circle at $E\ne X$ and $h$ the common tangent of the two circles at $X$. It follows that $\angle ABX=\angle CEX=180^\circ - \angle CBX$.

On the other hand,
$\angle XCE=\angle XAD$ because both of them are equal to $\angle \alpha$.